# My game size is larger than 150 MB and I am struggling to upload on both platforms. (Unity)

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity-container

I have a question regarding the upload of my game on Android playstore and iOS appstore. My game size is larger than 150 MB and I am struggling to upload on both platforms. I am writing this to you to ask how you manage to upload larger files or do you have any particular techniques that I may be able to use? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Jirawat, following article might be interesting for you, please read it carefully https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "Split Application Binary" for Android in order to get one .apk & one .obb file so that will fix your problem for Android.

Also check [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html#splitapplicationbinary:%7E:text=in%20debug%20builds.-,Split%20Application%20Binary,this%20if%20you%20want%20to%20publish%20applications%20larger%20than%20100%20MB.,-Updated%20features%20in)